# What does this number do in finding out the number of registry in RandomAcessFile (java)

Tags: java, file, random-access

I was wondering if anyone What does this number do, I have heard that it has to do something with bytes?, I really don't know.. could anyone please enlighten me:

```
public int total_reg() {
    try {
        int reg;
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(Ruta, "rw");
        reg = (int) file.length();
        file.close();
        return (int) reg / 684; //<---HERE WHAT IS THIS
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That file probably contains fixed-length records of 684 bytes each. That function would then return the number of records.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing the file being read stores fixed length records of length 684.  The method gets the number of bytes in the file and divides by the record length to get the total number of records.

Just a guess, given the information provided.

Comment: Agreed. After searching the webs, I haven't found anything that gives the number a purpose, and the fixed length makes sense. Searching `684 bytes` also showed a couple of other codes that returned numbers divided by 684.

Comment: Indeed, the only sensible explanation is that `684` is the length of a record in this file.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, Ruta would be a Route in Spanish. What file format are you reading? I think @Todd is on to something with the record length, so if you could look into the file format, it might help.